# What can I use to take frequencies from a song?

Tags: vb.net, audio-processing

I've written a VB.NET WinForms application that allows me to perform a Fourier Transform to find the amplitudes of discrete frequencies to represent that “strength” as a bar graph. The code for this is already ready and tested.

Since nobody could help with my last question [How do I get the wave (band) of the soundcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361480/how-do-i-get-the-wave-band-of-the-soundcard), I now had the idea of analyzing a piece of music for frequencies.

Where in the .mp3 file do I have to look? Is there a library in the Visual Studio Nuget package manager for this?

Comment: I think this is much too broad a question to be answered here, but I would suggest as your starting point to be able to process waveform audio data.  There are some docs in MSDN, but I'm not sure exactly what the best place would be to look there.

Answer (score 1):

first transform the mp3 into PCM format ( every language has many such libraries )  then feed the PCM array ( raw audio format )  into your FFT call which will return a new array of complex numbers ... iterate across this new array and make the calculation to determine magnitude given the complex number which is of the format A + Bi  (  real number A and the imaginary number B ) pair do this for each element of that new array ... here is the golang -ish  code I wrote which calculates the magnitude of each element of the new array ( generated from a FFT call )

```
number_of_samples := size of original PCM array 
nyquist_limit_index := int(number_of_samples / 2)

for index_fft, curr_complex := range complex_fft { // we really only use half this range + 1

    if index_fft <= nyquist_limit_index && curr_freq >= min_freq && curr_freq < max_freq {

        curr_real = real(curr_complex) // pluck out real portion of imaginary number
        curr_imag = imag(curr_complex) // ditto for im

        curr_mag = 2.0 * math.Sqrt(curr_real*curr_real+curr_imag*curr_imag) / number_of_samples  // magnitude of this freq

        curr_theta = math.Atan2(curr_imag, curr_real)  //  phase of this frequency

        curr_dftt := discrete_fft{

            real:      2.0 * curr_real,
            imaginary: 2.0 * curr_imag,
            magnitude: curr_mag,
            theta:     curr_theta,
        }

        *all_dft = append(*all_dft, curr_dftt)

        all_magnitudes = append(all_magnitudes, curr_mag)
    }
    curr_freq += incr_freq
}
```

Comment: Hi @Scott, thank you very much. I don't have enough reputation to give +1, but I really appreciate.